# Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS accessing array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I am using the routine for getting pixel colour (this one: http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/ ) and am faced with frequent app crashes when using it. The relevant portion of the code:

```
unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
if (data != NULL) {
    int offset = (some calculations here);
    int alpha = data[offset]; // <<<< crashes here
}
```

This code is linked to be ran on touchesBegan, touchesEnded and touchesMoved. It appears that the crashes occur during touchesEnded and touchesMoved events only, particularly when I start the touch on the target image, but move it off the boundaries of the image in the process.

Is there any way to check what is the size of the data in the array pointed to by `data` object? What could be going wrong there?

*Edit*:
The calculation of offset:

```
int offset = 4*((w*round(point.y)*x)+round(point.x)*x);
```

Where `point` is the point where touch occurs, `w` is the width if the image, `x` is the scale of the image (for hi-res images on retina displays).

I don't see anything wrong with the `cgctx` either. Basically, I am running the code from the link above almost unmodified, the particular code snippet I have problems with is in the function `(UIColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point` so if you want the details of what the code does, just read the source there.

Edit: another thing is that this never happens in the simulator, but often happens when testing on a device.

Edit: Ideally I'd want to do *nothing* if the finger is currently not over the image, but have trouble figuring out when that happens. It looks like the relevant methods in SDK only show what view the touch originated in, not where it is now. How can I figure that out?

Comment: Can you show the actual code in those three methods? Just edit your answer. For example, is your cgctx reference valid? Also, to get the length of data, you need to multiply the components by the height and width of your bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show all your work.   Your `offset` calculation is likely returning either a negative number or a number well beyond the end of the buffer.   Since `CG*` APIs often allocate rather large chunks of memory, often memory mapped, it is quite likely that the addresses before and after the allocation are unallocated/unmapped and, thus, access outside of the buffer leads to an immediate crash (as opposed to returning garbage).

Which is good.  Easier to debug.

You did provide a clue:

> move it off the boundaries of the
>   image in the process

I'd guess you modified the `offset` calculation to take the location of the touch.   And that location has moved beyond the bounds of the image and, thus, leads to a nonsense `offset` and a subsequent crash.

Fix that, and your app will stop crashing here.

---

Does your image *exactly* occupy the entire bounds of the item being touched?  I.e. does the thing handling the `touches*:` events have a bounds whose width and height are *exactly* the same as the image?

If not, you need to make sure you are correctly translating the coordinates from whatever is handling the touches to coordinates within the image.  Also note that the layout of bytes in an image is heavily dependent on exactly how the image was created and what internal color model it is using.

Comment: While debugging, I noticed that the numbers in `offset` are within the same range both when it crashes and when it executes with no problems, never negative either. See edits in original question.

Comment: Coincidence;  if it so happens that the memory after the buffer is allocated, you are likely reading garbage.

Comment: The image fills the view entirely. As to the bytes layout, that's not something I am familiar with, but the image originates as a .png file inserted into a view and is held in an instance variable of that view. It's static so the size of the view is matched to the size of the image right at init time and never changes.

Comment: Something weird happens specifically when the touch is *moved* outside of the boundaries of the image. It's not something I can prevent, but worse, I cannot even predict that in my program - don't know how. Ideally I'd want to do *nothing* if the finger is currently not over the image, but have trouble figuring out when that happens.

Comment: The key is to translate the touch event from the coordinate system of the view into the coordinate system of your image while also capping it at the border of your images.  If you know the image width and you see an X coordinate beyond that width, you know the drag left the image's content area.